# How to fill color in a cell in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to color cells that have "#N/A" value in the currentsheet. In order to do this i use following macro:

```
Sub ColorCells()

Dim Data As Range
Dim cell As Range
Set currentsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Comparison")
Set Data = currentsheet.Range("A2:AW1048576")

For Each cell In Data
If cell.Value = "#N/A" Then
   cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End If
Next

End Sub
```

But the line `If cell.Value = "#N/A" Then` gives an error: Type mismatch. Maybe someone can help to understand where is the error? Thanks

Comment: why not just to use conditional formatting to highlight cells with errors?) If you don't like it, use `If cell.Text = "#N/A" Then`. One more tip, try to use `Set Data = Intersect(currentsheet.UsedRange,currentsheet.Range("A2:AW1048576"))` to minimize count of cell in loop. Now you loop throught *50 mln* cells:)

Comment: You can also use `IsError(Cell.Value)`

Comment: instead **.value** use **.text**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Non VBA Solution:**

Use Conditional Formatting rule with formula: `=ISNA(A1)` (to highlight cells with *all errors* - not only `#N/A`, use `=ISERROR(A1)`)

[image]

**VBA Solution:**

Your code loops through *50 mln* cells. To reduce number of cells, I use `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16)` and `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 16)`to return only cells with errors (note, I'm using `If cell.Text = "#N/A" Then`)

```
Sub ColorCells()
    Dim Data As Range, Data2 As Range, cell As Range
    Dim currentsheet As Worksheet

    Set currentsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Comparison")

    With currentsheet.Range("A2:AW" & Rows.Count)
        .Interior.Color = xlNone
        On Error Resume Next
        'select only cells with errors
        Set Data = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16)
        Set Data2 = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 16)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    If Not Data2 Is Nothing Then
        If Not Data Is Nothing Then
            Set Data = Union(Data, Data2)
        Else
            Set Data = Data2
        End If
    End If

    If Not Data Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In Data
            If cell.Text = "#N/A" Then
               cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

**Note**, to highlight cells witn any error (not only `"#N/A"`), replace following code

```
If Not Data Is Nothing Then
   For Each cell In Data
       If cell.Text = "#N/A" Then
          cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
       End If
   Next
End If
```

with

```
If Not Data Is Nothing Then Data.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```

**UPD:** (how to add CF rule through VBA)

```
Sub test()
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Comparison").Range("A2:AW" & Rows.Count).FormatConditions
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=ISNA(A1)"
        .Item(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank YOU! It works fine, both methods! 

The only problem with VBA if i need to run macro with another input and  position of N/A cells changes, this macro does not rewrite the color. For example if A2 cell was colored it remains colored even if from the second attempt there is no N/A value anymore.

Comment: @Ale, in that case add line `currentsheet.Range("A2:AW" & Rows.Count).Interior.Color = xlNone` just before `On Error Resume Next` (see my updated answer)

Comment: It works, just the problem is that it deletes all the color from all the document, but i need to delete color just from N/A cells. Anyway thank you a lot!

Comment: @Ale, as I understood, cells doesn't have `#N/A` *anymore* that's why you should delete color. There're two options for you: 1) loop throught each cell and check `if cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then `cell.Interior.Color = xlNone` 2) create CF rule from VBA (better one)

Comment: Could be that A column must be always colored in grey, but the column B contains some values and N/A, colored in red. Cells that contain N/A depend on input file and another macro. So in case N/A position changes, i have to clear red color from previous time, but still leaving A column colored in grey. But in this case probably better to use CF. THANKS!

Comment: @Ale, see my updated part on how to create CF rule through VBA:)

Comment: Thanks, it works fine! 
But then i actually recorded a Macro doing CF, so the VBA created the commands automatically. :)

Answer (score 4):

1. Use conditional formatting instead of VBA to  highlight errors.
2. Using a VBA loop like the one you posted will take a long time to process
3. the statement `If cell.Value = "#N/A" Then` will never work. If you insist on using VBA to highlight errors, try this instead.

   Sub ColorCells()

   ```
   Dim Data As Range
   Dim cell As Range
   Set currentsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Comparison")
   Set Data = currentsheet.Range("A2:AW1048576")

   For Each cell In Data

   If IsError(cell.Value) Then
      cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
   End If
   Next

   End Sub
   ```
4. Be prepared for a long wait, since the procedure loops through 51 million cells
5. There are more efficient ways to achieve what you want to do. Update your question if you have a change of mind.

Comment: Thanks  You! Well actually i was searching for VBA solution, but it works ok.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select all cells by left-top corner
2. Choose [Home] >> [Conditional Formatting] >> [New Rule]
3. Choose [Format only cells that contain]
4. In [Format only cells with:], choose **"Errors"**
5. Choose proper formats in [Format..] button

Answer (score 0):

You need to use cell.Text = "#N/A" instead of cell.Value = "#N/A". The error in the cell is actually just text stored in the cell.