# Change Background when formula removed by user change

Tags: excel, vba

**Aim:**

Change background colour if there is no formula (when user overrides defaults formula goes and this needs to be highlighted)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Set currentsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Audit Findings")    
'#############
'CHECK IF ANY MISSING FORMULAS WHERE NOT ALLOWED
Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = currentsheetRange("J7:J11")

For Each cell In rng

    If cell.HasFormula Then
      Range(cell.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
      ' MsgBox "Cell " & cell.Address & " contains a formula."
    Else
        Range(cell.Address).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
       'MsgBox "The cell has no formula."
    End If
  
Next cell    
 
'#############

'CHECK IF ANY BLANKS WHERE NOT ALLOWED
On Error GoTo Whoa

Application.EnableEvents = False
'Set range to check
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E7:J11")) Is Nothing Then
     'check length and reverse if blank as has to be a value
     '#################
If Len(Trim(Target.Value)) = 0 Then Application.Undo
End If
     
LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue


End Sub
```

**References:**

[Looping](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/loop-through-defined-range.html)

[Cell content](https://sitestory.dk/excel_vba/cell_testing.htm)

[Background colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22193415/how-to-fill-color-in-a-cell-in-vba)

Comment: Is this the entire code? I just tested it and it worked fine.

Comment: Is your sheet protected?

Comment: Added full data, oh yes it is protected! That might not help!

Comment: No, you need to either unprotect in your code, make the changes and then protect again or use `Worksheet.Protect "Password", UserInterfaceOnly := True` This allows VBA to make changes.

Comment: @SJR spot on, unprotected/protected and fixed. Thanks, if you put as the answer I'll upvote and mark as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine (except in the code you provided in both cases you change the interior color to red).

I would move this code to the `Worksheet_Change` event, and then just scan that the cells being modifed fall inside your scanned range (the `For Each cell In rng` loop is not needed anymore)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim WatchRange                  As Range
Dim IntersectRange              As Range

' modify range to suit your needs
Set WatchRange = Range("J7:J11")
Set IntersectRange = Intersect(Target, WatchRange)

If Not IntersectRange Is Nothing Then

    If Target.HasFormula Then
      Target.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) ' has formula >> color green
      ' MsgBox "Cell " & cell.Address & " contains a formula."
    Else
        Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' has no formula >> color red
       'MsgBox "The cell has no formula."
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I guess it's possible that more than one cell is being changed?

Comment: Just one cell, I've updated my own code with this as well, bonus!